# Launching firefox selenium webdriver denied permissions on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: selenium, firefox, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, permission-denied

I'm trying to deploy my website to Elastic Beanstalk, but I ran into a problem. My website uses Selenium to scrape another website (I couldn't scrape it using any other library because it's a very annoying site). I managed to install Firefox on the EB server using this guide https://lambda-linux.io/blog/2015/01/28/announcing-firefox-browser-support-for-amazon-linux/, but now when I try to use my site and it tries to launch the Firefox webdriver, I get this error:

```
WebDriverException at / Message: Failed to start browser: permission denied
```

Here is the code that attempts to launch the webdriver:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('/home/ec2-user/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/opt/python/current/app/api/geckodriver', firefox_binary=binary)
```

I searched many forums and sites to find an answer if it's even possible to run Selenium on EB, but couldn't find a definitive answer. I would love to know if it is and if it is, in fact, possible, then how do I attain the permissions to do it (hopefully, that's also possible). Thank you! (also, I will gladly drop any code, logs etc. if needed)

Comment: Is this a python website? How do you add selenium to your application?

Comment: Two years, yet no answer. I'm trying to do this exact thing... did you give up on it?

Comment: @KyleBurkett yes, unfortunately, I gave up with EB and used DigitalOcean instead (it works there). Good luck!

Comment: @Maximka , thanks, actually I decided to just go with a straight ec2 instance... may look into digital ocean to see if they have better ci&cd capabilities. I updated the answer for you 
─=≡Σ((( つ◕ل͜◕)つ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Use digital ocean or just a straight ec2 instance instead of elastic beanstalk